# getting columns values using row id jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jaquery code like this:

```
var items = $('.trSelected', grid);
```

where items is comma seperated list of  rows (tr tags) like this:

```
row25
row30
```

I want to to get 6th and 8th column ( td) value of these rows. How to do it using jquery.

I can iterate through items like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
   itemList += items[i].id;  // gives row id
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The fallowing code iterates in your rows and add the values of 6th and 8th to the itemList.

```
$.each( items, function(i, item){

     columns = $(item).children();
     //columns[5]
     //columns[7]
});
```

Comment: I need value of 6th and 8th column of each selected row.

Comment: how can i get innerhtml of these columns ? I tried to use columns[5].text() but it gives error.

Comment: Your columns[5] is a html element, to call .text you have to pass to jquery constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function and pass the row number and column into that, check the return is not null etc and you should get the value you need from the table directly

```
function getValue(rowNumber, column){


var val = $('#selectme').children('tbody').children(':nth-child(' + rowNumber + ')').children(':nth-child(' + column + ')').text();

    return val;

}
alert(getValue(1,3));
```

​

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vaGKH/3/)